# Unable to set cookies in Chrome using Flask-JWT-Extended, React, and Axios

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies, axios, cross-domain

**Background and Issues**

I have a Flask back-end running in localhost:5000 and a React SPA running on localhost:3000.
I was able to make them talk but when trying to store the token generated from Flask into Browser's cookies 1) response headers does not contain any cookies when doing `console.log(response)` after a successful POST from `axios` and 2) the cookies are not being set. But when inspecting the network > Login.js header, I could actually see the `Set-Cookie` key exists as response's header. I've tried multiple solutions from Google and StackOverflow but no solution seems to work here and I really can't figure out what is going on as the request is being made successfully, and Chrome is allowing third party software to set the cookies. And even I can see the tokens from Network > Login.js header.

**Steps**

1) Users enters in their username and password and hit login.

2) Axios POST call is made to Flask's back-end.

3) Process the data and generates a couple of tokens and set them into cookies.

4) Browser's cookie are set with few tokens. <- this part is not working.

**Code**

**Flask back-end token generation using `flask-jwt-extended`**

```
# app_config related to flask-jwt-extended
CORS_HEADERS = "Content-Type"
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ["cookies"]
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True



# post method from flask-restful for LoginAPI class
def post(self):
    email = request.json.get("email")
    password = request.json.get("password")

    # some processing here.....
    payload = {
        "email": email
    }

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=payload)
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=payload)

    response = jsonify({"status": True})
    set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
    set_refresh_cookies(response, refresh_token)

    return response
```

**CORS using `flask-cors`**

```
# in below code, I had some issues with putting wildcard (*) into origin, so I've specified to the React SPA's host and port.
CORS(authentication_blueprint, resources={r"/authentication/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}},
     supports_credentials=True)
```

**React SPA - making a post call using `axios`**

```
# also tried `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;` but same result.
export const login = (email, password, cookies) => {
return dispatch => {
    const authData = {
        email: email,
        password: password
    };

    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/authentication/login/';

    axios.post(url, authData, {withCredentials: true)
        .then(
            response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });

    dispatch(authSuccess(email, password));
    }
};
```

**Below image is the response from successful post call in `axios`.**
I'm not sure whether it is normal but response's headers are not showing any of the cookies that I'm setting from the back-end.

[image]

**And below image is from Network > header for login/**

As shown, you can clearly see the token information with `Set-Cookie` key. I've also checked that they aren't `secure`.

[image]

And finally when I check my cookie tab from application > cookies, I do not see anything.

Comment: If I were you, I would send the token in a json response and set the cookie in frontend. Much cleaner api if not using UI for requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issues were coming from the `localhost`.

> I have a Flask back-end running in localhost:5000 and a React SPA running on localhost:3000.

From above statement, to be very specific, I was running the back-end on localhost:5000 and running the React SPA on 127.0.0.1:3000.

Once I've changed the `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`, it worked like a charm.

And a side note, after playing around with `CORS`, I think it will be a lot easier to use `Nginx` and `proxy_pass` to pass the request coming from React SPA to back-end to avoid using `CORS` completely, because if one have to use the `CORS` in different environment such as test, staging and etcs, one would have to set up the `CORS` at the web server level e.g) `Nginx` anyway and it requires slightly different configuration that how I set up for local environment anyway.

Comment: Hello, I am having the exact same issue as you. And all my configurations are similar to yours... Any idea where the problem can come from ?